# Li-po battery reported voltage has deviations. Why?

Tags: battery-charging, raspberry-pi, charging, lipo, discharge

The chart below is a 4 hour logging of a 3500 mAh Li-po battery voltage (no charging - powering up a Raspberry Pi Zero W). The charging board uses BQ24160 chip to read the BAT voltage.
I use 3200~4200 mV as 0~100% range and show the battery charge percentage to the user.

As you can see, the voltage fluctuates a lot.  With these devitations, the percentage goes up and down!

Can someone explain this?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a trace or recording of the current being delivered from the battery? If so, is it equally spiky? If not, can you tell us about the workload that the Rpi Zero W (and any connected peripherals) was running? Was that workload itself spiky?

Comment: Tbh if you disregard the big spike, you are looking at drops of 25 mV or less. This, depending on where this is measured, does not seem like very much when the official site recommends a 2 A power supply. Spikes of 100s of mA or maybe even 1 A draw from the CPU itself could easily create this

Comment: @nanofarad, No, I don't have current log. Connected peripherals: 1-MFRC522 board ( ON, idle ) 2- 3.5" LCD, always ON. WiFi is up and I have a ssh session up. My program ( written in C# ) is idle, too.

Comment: @Linkyyy, I was curious if there is a problem on the battery side.

Comment: If you don’t want to capture small transients, have you considered either analog or digital low pass filtering?

Comment: @winny, I may apply a simple Moving Average on the recorded voltages and use this to calculate the voltage percentage instead of using actual values.

Comment: What are you wanting to see? A clean straight line? You're not going to get that because of noise as well as the RPI's transient activities affecting current draw which in turn affect voltage droop.

Comment: Without to the rest of us any known requirement, you may do whatever you want. Edit your question and post your requirements.